# Unstable wireless connection in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, 64-bit

I have recently upgraded to 14.04, and I have realized that after certain periods of time from connecting to a wifi network, my computer suddenly disconnects and i have to disable and then enable wifi again to connect. This is a major issue for me especially when downloading files. Any fixes? I have already tried disabling IPv6 as some posts suggested in addition to other fixes. Please help, my computer runs 64 bit.

Here is the result of running the script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux Bilal-Satellite-C655D 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8181]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet [1969:2060] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

##### lsusb #####

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 10f1:1a34 Importek 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

rtl8192ce              53550  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        53172  1 rtl8192ce
mac80211              630653  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"B D HOME"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:81   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            atl1c
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [B D HOME] ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192ce
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           18 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    BlueSky:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA2
    Name FA9911.:    Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA WPA2
    moaaz:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA
    fadi:            Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA
    MikroTik-A60863: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    free set up 186kb 15$ 70.926915: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 27
    fre set 512kb 25$ 70.926915: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27
    for internet cafe 33$ 70.926915: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40
    fre set 512/512 25$ 71/566484: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37
    fre set 2mb/1.5m 45$ 71/566484: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37
    phone 10$ unlimited 70.926915: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37
    fre set 384/384 20$ 71/566484: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34
    network cafe 44$ 71/566484: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30
    new for dealers acc 8$ 70.926915: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37
    fre set 384kb 20$ 70.926915: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37
    *B D HOME:       Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 56 WPA WPA2
    fre set 1m 33$ 70.926915: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.2
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"B D HOME"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000054e91bcb4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000842204420484F4D45
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180204F0000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"new for dealers acc 8$ 70.926915"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001674f6459ac
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4264ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00206E657720666F72206465616C657273206163632038242037302E393236393135
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD2A000C42000000011E00000000006614030000303030323646363941423533000000000000000005026C09
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"fre set 384kb 20$ 70.926915"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001674f645f12
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4264ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 001B66726520736574203338346B62203230242037302E393236393135
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD2A000C42000000011E00000000006614030000303030323646363941423533000000000000000005026C09
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"fre set 2.5mb 45$ 70.926915"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001674f64644e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4260ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 001B6672652073657420322E356D62203435242037302E393236393135
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD2A000C42000000011E00000000006614030000303030323646363941423533000000000000000005026C09
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BlueSky"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000323d91340
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0007426C7565536B79
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201F0000000
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Name FA9911."
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C4E616D65204641393931312E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A1C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606081500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180202000C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"fadi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000006b08c8181
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2544ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000466616469
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010060FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD050050F20500
                    IE: Unknown: DD0E0050F204104A0001101044000102

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     EF063698748457BBEDB4633
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008176sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008177sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008178sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008191sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,rtl8192c-common,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     D5E4890DC428FA5A1BF92DF
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     E1F4663325225EE8DBA54CA
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     32F826C623BC49F764F7974
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

loop
lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x1969:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/0000:06:00.0 (atl1c)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:02:00.0 (rtl8192ce)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[    3.247310] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x250f01)
[   18.646342] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[   18.730826] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   18.731483] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   22.877235] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   22.879133] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   25.091042] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   25.114153] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   25.116811] wlan0: authenticated
[   25.117317] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   25.117325] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   25.130018] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   25.135637] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[   25.135898] wlan0: associated
[   25.135974] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   25.357409] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=2)
[   25.382134] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   25.382338] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   25.384936] wlan0: authenticated
[   25.385261] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   25.385269] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   25.385434] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   25.392661] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[   25.392859] wlan0: associated
[ 1782.666156] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 7)
[ 1783.946838] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1783.947159] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1783.955463] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1783.955883] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1783.955890] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 1783.959855] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1783.962619] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[ 1783.962863] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: You can try to update to 14.04.1. They added a lot of new hardware support in this update.

Comment: how do i do that? I cannot find it under software update

Comment: I just checked and I already have 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: reinstall the driver packages: `linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: @WildMan: I have edited the question to contain the results of running the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This driver is problematic but there are a few things we can do to help it work better usually.

First in your router change `802.11bgn` to `802.11bg`.

Second change the wpa/wpa2 encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

Third set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.

Fourth go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Fifth open the terminal CTRL+ALT+_T then copy and paste the following code one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rtl8192ce swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8192ce
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce
```