# WiFi Disconnects After A While In Fresh-Installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I know there are already a lot of issues about this but I've tried some tips like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504777/unstable-wireless-connection-in-ubuntu-14-04) but none works.

My linux version

```
uname -a
Linux petra-Lenovo-G40-70 3.16.0-031600-lowlatency #201408031935 SMP 
 PREEMPT Sun Aug 3 23:44:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(I upgraded the kernel just to see if it had some effect. Turns out it didn't).

Here's my wireless_script output

http://pastebin.com/BEWV4DHE

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 08 Dec 2014 11:52 WIB +0700

Booted last: 08 Dec 2014 11:47 WIB +0700

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-031600-lowlatency #201408031935 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 3 23:44:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

snd_soc_rt5640         93123  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
ideapad_laptop         18523  0 
rtl8723be              87260  0 
snd_soc_core          202421  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               105002  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
btcoexist              55886  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         23427  1 rtl8723be
sparse_keymap          13890  1 ideapad_laptop
rtl_pci                27306  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                69157  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              699524  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              533464  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.10.10.49  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b210:41ff:fe1b:7b77/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2243924 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:598917 (598.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-10 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:20   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1] ---------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           65 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-2: Infra, <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-2' [AC7]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-1: Infra, <MAC 'URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-1' [AC2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-2: Infra, <MAC 'URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-2' [AC6]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    Lenovo A369i:    Infra, <MAC 'Lenovo A369i' [AC5]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    InmagineX2000:   Infra, <MAC 'InmagineX2000' [AN5]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    *URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1: Infra, <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1' [AC1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA2
    Designer2:       Infra, <MAC 'Designer2' [AC4]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA2
    XTRANS1:         Infra, <MAC 'XTRANS1' [AC3]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74
    Arie’s iMac:   Infra, <MAC 'Arie’s iMac' [AN9]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA2
    XTRANS3:         Infra, <MAC 'XTRANS3' [AN10]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.10.10.49
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.10.10.1

    DNS:             202.138.224.24
    DNS:             202.138.224.22
    DNS:             180.131.145.145
    DNS:             180.131.144.144
    DNS:             10.10.10.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Petra's iPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Petra's iPhone | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Petra's iPhone | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dlink]] (600 root)
[connection] id=dlink | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=dlink | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-2 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jakarta (based on set time zone)

country ID:
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      7   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-10 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000004ba765ae801
                    Extra: Last beacon: 14ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-1' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=30 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000004ba7659fb01
                    Extra: Last beacon: 507ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'XTRANS1' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"XTRANS1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000057a51fab3
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3992ms ago
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'Designer2' [AC4]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Designer2"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000002887cdc41
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3946ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'Lenovo A369i' [AC5]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Lenovo A369i"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000016318876
                    Extra: Last beacon: 14ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-2' [AC6]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-28 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"URBANINDO-GUEST-LT-2"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=320004c4800096ce
                    Extra: Last beacon: 14ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-2' [AC7]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-14 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-2"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000004c480007fee
                    Extra: Last beacon: 14ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C94095C986767A931B924EF
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2C:88:2A:97:22:6B:C4:D2:E6:B0:88:C1:16:D6:EF:6B:3B:25:CC:00
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     7410431A59C24B1BC33226E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2C:88:2A:97:22:6B:C4:D2:E6:B0:88:C1:16:D6:EF:6B:3B:25:CC:00
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     3273ECD6028617EFD27E4F4
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2C:88:2A:97:22:6B:C4:D2:E6:B0:88:C1:16:D6:EF:6B:3B:25:CC:00
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8362106E96F806A9DBAE565
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2C:88:2A:97:22:6B:C4:D2:E6:B0:88:C1:16:D6:EF:6B:3B:25:CC:00
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-lowlatency/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     E4D3FCB715C0CB33E42D11E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2C:88:2A:97:22:6B:C4:D2:E6:B0:88:C1:16:D6:EF:6B:3B:25:CC:00
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-lowlatency/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D86AFD97E7F71C59777C05F
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2C:88:2A:97:22:6B:C4:D2:E6:B0:88:C1:16:D6:EF:6B:3B:25:CC:00
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
debug: 0
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   51.417675] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[   54.324745] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   54.324959] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   58.307392] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   59.464523] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1' [AC1]>
[   59.474735] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   59.478731] wlan0: authenticated
[   59.478970] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   59.486453] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'URBANINDO-OFFICE-LT-1' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   59.486580] wlan0: associated
[   59.486600] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the parameter of wireless driver as follows and check the reported issuse.

change 802.11bgn to 802.11bg.

```
iwconfig wlan0 modu 11g
```

change the wep encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

Set your wireless channel in the router to 11 and then save the router configuration and reboot it.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
```

Go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Now open the terminal CTRL+ALT+_T then copy and paste the following code one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rtl8723be swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be
```

IF the issue persists, try compiling new driver. Hope this helps!

Comment: `iwconfig wlan0 modu 11g` returns `Error for wireless request "Set Modulation" (8B2F): SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported"`

Comment: changing the wireless channel alone sometime will help you to fix the issue

Comment: weird,, can't do that also. `sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11` returns `Device or resource busy`. I tried turning of the WiFi, it also returns that message.

Comment: trying the last one. i hope it works.

Comment: nope, the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your wireless adapter is not disabled. You can check it by running:

```
rfkill list
```

To enable wireless adapters, run:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```